# Jquery getJson not working with php json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ember.js

Here is the sample php json_encode output

```
{"user_id":34543456532,"user_status":true,"name":"ABC","propic":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/....."}
```

I'm using ember so the Route is

```
  model: function(params) {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      uposts: tweets,
      ustat: [$.getJSON( "status.php")]
    });
  }
```

The HTML/Handlebars code to handle this is

```
{{#if ustat.[0].user_status}}
do something
{{else}}
do something else
{{/if}}
```

However the **user_status** always returns false, when I'm using some dummy values like

```
  model: function(params) {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      uposts: tweets,
      ustat: [{"user_id":34543456532,"user_status":true,"name":"ABC","propic":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/....."}]
    });
  }
```

it works fine, where is the error and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: `getJSON` does asynchronous (AJAX) request by default which doesn't suit to your case. You have to do synchronous request. This can be done by `$.ajax` with `async` option

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` does not return the data from the call, it returns a promise. Perhaps something like this would work better:

```
$.getJSON( "status.php").then(function(statusData){
   ...
   model: function(params) {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      uposts: tweets,
      ustat: [statusData]
    });
   }
   ...
});
```